# Send variable from php script to a python script

Tags: php, python

I want to pass a php variable to python script and then use it for execution in pyhton. Then I want to pass the result of the python script back to php file

Tried this :

test.php:

```
 <?php
 $param = 6;
 $result= shell_exec("python C:/xampp/htdocs/test/script.py $param");
 echo $result;
?>
```

script.py:

```
  import sys

  x = sys.argv[1]
  print (x)
  r = x + 5

  print (r)
```

I'm getting a blank screen when I try to run test.php on browser meaning the variables are not being passed. I want to use the results from python script in php for further calculations.

I'm running both the codes on Windows interface.

Comment: Maybe check if result is null, reading the docs for shell_exec says it will return null if anything goes wrong. Also just so you know your code is vulnerable to shell injection if $param is not trusted

Comment: PD of [How can I debug exec() problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/12199353) / [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](//stackoverflow.com/q/845021)